# UNITY - FB SDK : screenshot not getting posted on profile

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to integrate FB SDK in my UNITY GAME for ios and ANDROID.
FB SHARE AND INVITE are working fine which are in "FBSCENE" scene.
But in "GAME" scene i want to take a SCREENSHOT after game is finished and post it on users FB WALL.
I read "Take and publish a screenshot" under EXAMPLE at       **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API**
and my code is this

```
public void screenShareFB()
{
    callFB ();
}
void callFB () {
    if (!FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);                                                                                                                                                                
    }
    else {
        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshot());
    }
}

void LoginCallback(FBResult result) {                                                                                          
    FbDebug.Log("LoginCallback");                                                          
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) { 
        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshot());
    }                                                                                      
}
/*
void OnLoggedIn() {                                                                                          
    FbDebug.Log("Logged in. ID: " + FB.UserId);                                            
}*/

private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot() {
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
    wwwForm.AddField("message", "herp derp.  I did a thing!  Did I do this right?");

    FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
    Debug.Log("done");
}
private Texture2D lastResponseTexture;
private string lastResponse = "";
public string ApiQuery = "";
void Callback(FBResult result)
{
    lastResponseTexture = null;
    if (result.Error != null)
        lastResponse = "Error Response: " + result.Error;
    else if (!ApiQuery.Contains("/picture"))
        lastResponse = "Success Response: " + result.Text;
    else
    {
        lastResponseTexture = result.Texture;
        lastResponse = "Success Response: ";
    }
}
```

screenShareFB() being called when user tap on SHARE SCREENSHOT button.
NOTE:
I have called FB.Init(with a call back method); in Start() of the script.
I am using C# script.
Is this because my app is not live on facebook ?
I have configured it on facebook already.
I was testing on PC.

Please tell me if anything is wrong with the code or any thing i am missing.

Comment: Note I am using facebook sdk ver 6.0 and unity 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was permissions.
the "publish_actions" permission was not review by facebook.
thus the screenshot was not getting published.
but 1 thing when try to fill details for fb to review my app and allow me to access publish_actions for my user.
They require us to add a "platform" under "SETTINGS" in "BASIC".
Now i am using UNITY.
which is not mentioned as a platform there.
What should i do.?

Comment: but you have to go to developer.facebook.com and apply for a publish_actions permission. and have to submit some details. And the you are done

Comment: It works for me : the app is public in settings and publish_action is not reviewed yet. It works for admin atleast.